# Use MySQL Procedure along with a Function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, user-defined-functions, procedures

I have a fully working user defined function called `CalculateDistance` which will calculate the distance between the provided postcode and the one within the function.

I want to know if there is some way to use this function to create some extra data. I want a query that will fetch all of the data from the database, as well as provide this distance calculation.

In simple terms, I have a database full of rental properties and the attributes are: `Name`, `Description` and `Postcode`. I have other attributes which I have stripped away. I want to be able to call a query in PHP like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Properties WITH DistanceTo = CalculateDistance(Postcode) ORDER BY ID ASC")){;
while($PropertyInfo = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
echo $PropertyInfo['Name'];
    echo $PropertyInfo['DistanceTo'];
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `WITH` be `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

To show the distance and filter by the distance your query should be something like

```
SELECT p.*, CalculateDistance(p.Postcode) [Distance]
FROM Properties p
WHERE p.DistanceTo = CalculateDistance(p.Postcode) 
ORDER BY ID ASC
```